# How to get the value of "Label" inside the repeater?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Hi I just wanna ask on how to get the value of Label inside the repeater. I want to pass the value of "lblProduct" on the command name ="ViewDetails". Thanks

```
<asp:Repeater ID="reptrData" runat="server" >
         <ItemTemplate>
             <div>
               <h6>Product Details</h6>
                 <asp:Panel ID="PanelHeader" runat="server" CssClass="ui-widget-header">
                     <table>
                         <tr>
                             <td><b>Product:</b></td> 
                             <td><asp:Label ID="lblProduct" runat ="server"><%#Eval("plCode")%></asp:Label>
                             </td>
                            </tr>
                         <tr>
                             <td><b>Date:</b></td>
                             <td><asp:Label ID="lblDate" runat ="server"><%#Eval("plDate")%></asp:Label>
                             </td>
                         </tr>
                    </table>
                </asp:Panel>
            </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `FindControl` method of the repeater item to find the Label:

```
protected void reptrData_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    Label lblProduct = e.Item.FindControl("lblProduct") as Label;
    string product = lblProduct.Text;
}
```

For some reason, the text of the Label is empty in code-behind when I use your current markup. If the `Text` property of the Label is used to set the content, however, it can be retrieved:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="reptrData" runat="server" onitemcommand="reptrData_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div>
            <h6>
                Product Details</h6>
            <asp:Panel ID="PanelHeader" runat="server" CssClass="ui-widget-header">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <b>Product:</b>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblProduct" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("plCode") %>' />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <b>Date:</b>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("plDate") %>' />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </asp:Panel>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

N.B. I also added the closing tag for the `div` element in the ItemTemplate.

Comment: @CannorsFan Thank you so much \m/

Answer (score 0):

Use `FindControl()` method to get to the label control and then get it's text like

```
Label lbl1 = (Label)reptrData.FindControl("lblProduct");
Response.Write(lbl1.Text);
```

You should change your design ASPX code and have the value in `Text` property for the label like

```
<td><asp:Label ID="lblProduct" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("plCode")%>'></asp:Label></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to Get the Lable value I think It is best to use input and then give a name attribute to that Input for example :

```
<asp:Repeater ID="reptrData" runat="server" >
         <ItemTemplate>
             <div>
               <h6>Product Details</h6>
                 <asp:Panel ID="PanelHeader" runat="server" CssClass="ui-widget-header">
                     <table>
                         <tr>
                             <td><b>Product:</b></td> 
                             <td><span name="lblProduct" ><%#Eval("plCode")%></span>
                             </td>
                            </tr>
                         <tr>
                             <td><b>Date:</b></td>
                             <td><span name="lblDate"><%#Eval("plDate")%></span>
                             </td>
                         </tr>
                    </table>
                </asp:Panel>
            </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

After that you can get the list of value by

```
HttpContext.Current.Request["lblProduct"]
```

and then if you you want to find an specific Lable you can Add ID of each Row to Name and Get the Value By Request and Specific Name Like this :

```
<asp:Repeater ID="reptrData" runat="server" >
             <ItemTemplate>
                 <div>
                   <h6>Product Details</h6>
                     <asp:Panel ID="PanelHeader" runat="server" CssClass="ui-widget-header">
                         <table>
                             <tr>
                                 <td><b>Product:</b></td> 
                                 <td><span name="lblProduct<%#Eval("ID")%>" ><%#Eval("plCode")%></span>
                                 </td>
                                </tr>
                             <tr>
                                 <td><b>Date:</b></td>
                                 <td><span name="lblDate<%#Eval("ID")%>"><%#Eval("plDate")%></span>
                                 </td>
                             </tr>
                        </table>
                    </asp:Panel>
                </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

and then in your code

string value = HttpContext.Current.Request["lblDate1"];

For More in formation Look : [Getting the value of a label from HttpContext.Current.Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503654/getting-the-value-of-a-label-from-httpcontext-current-request)
[Get the value of Label in listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20569341/get-the-value-of-label-in-listview)